# How to handle pagnation on firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to handle pagination on my firestore, at first it was working when i have `StartAfter`, but i was having like 5 document in my collection, after deleting to 1 document,

i keep getting `BAD Request` so i change it to `StartAt` still yet, is not working

```
  async myForumQuestions(id: string, page = 1, pageSize =10): Promise<object> {
    const skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    const refDocs = admin.firestore().collection("forum").orderBy("timeStamp").where("createdby", "==", id);

    const totalDocs = await refDocs.get().then((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.size);
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalDocs / pageSize);

    // Fetch the data with pagination
    const myQuestionData: ForumInterface[] = await refDocs
        .startAt(skip) // when it was startAfter and document is more than 5 it works but now document is 1 not working anymore
        .limit(pageSize)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) =>
          querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data() as ForumInterface)
        );


    const quoteIds = myQuestionData
        .filter((question) => question.quoteId !== undefined)
        .map((question) => question.quoteId);

    // Fetch all quoteData in one go
    const quoteData = await admin.firestore().collection("forum")
        .where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", quoteIds)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          const data: { [id: string]: ForumInterface } = {};
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            data[doc.id] = doc.data() as ForumInterface;
          });
          return data;
        });

    // Assign quoteData to questions
    myQuestionData.forEach((question) => {
      if (question.quoteId !== undefined) {
        question.quoteData = quoteData[question.quoteId] || undefined;
      }
    });
    return {
      data: myQuestionData,
      pagination: {
        page: page,
        total_pages: totalPages,
      },
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination in Firestore is based on **cursors**, not on offsets, which means that this won't work:

```
const skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;

...

.startAt(skip)
```

Instead of passing an offset count, you need to pass the `DocumentSnapshot` of the document that you want to start at to `startAt`.

I recommend reading the documenation on [paginating data with query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors), including the video in there, and some of the many other [questions about Firestore pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5d%5bjavascript%5d%20pagination%20offset&searchOn=3).

---

Since you are using the Node.js SDK, you can use its [`offset()` function](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/query#_google_cloud_firestore_Query_offset_member_1_) - which actually *do* take an offset value. Just be aware that you'll pay document read cost for the skipped document in that case.

Comment: thanks for the response, i am still confuse, i am will like to show you the improved code base `on the documentation` i read..